# Get count for date between start date and start date + days left

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model:

```py
class Banner(models.Model):
   date_start=models.DateField()
   days_left=models.IntegerField()
   ...
```

I need to create a function, that will return count of models, where input date is between model's `date_start` and `date_start + days_left`. For example:

`model1` and `model2` `date_start` field is 26.04.2023

`model1` `days_left` is 3 and `model2` `days_left` is 8

For date 27.04.2023 function should return 2, but if date is 01.05.2023 it should return 1 (cause `model1.date_start + datetime.timedelta(days=model1.days_left))` will be 29.04.2023, and date is not in that range)

Which is the best way to do that? I think it should be some kind of Django ORM function, but i can't figure that.

Comment: Calculating with time is not very convenient in Django. In that case it might even be better to work with a `TimeDeltaField` for `days_left` instead.